# thinking sphinx error when rake thinking_sphinx:start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10' for search functionality.I am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx tutorial for this.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx.git
rake thinking_sphinx:index
```

These 2 steps executed without any problem,but when i did rake thinking_sphinx:start it was giving following error :

```
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/user/newsvn/alumnicell/log/searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/user/newsvn/alumnicell/log/searchd.log
```

I searched on net about this but even trying many solutions i am not able to solve this error.Also while checking on net i came to know that there should be sphinx.yml file in config which is not present in my project.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved it...
i just added sphinx.yml file inside config and specified port number for each environment as follows:

```
development:
  port: 9310
  morphology: stem_en

test:
  port: 9310
  morphology: stem_en

production:
  port: 9310
  morphology: stem_en
```

then changed listen address in development.sphinx.conf for searchd as follows:

```
searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9310
}
```

then on console ran command:

```
rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild
```

Comment: was the same port being used. Thanx a ton

Answer (score 0):

May be `/home/user/newsvn/alumnicell/log/searchd.log` has solution for the problem.

Just post it!

Comment: Yes man, In my case I checked this file: `../yourdirectory/log/searchd.log` and it was written that: `/usr/local/var/data/binlog.002: No such file or directory` I only do this:

`touch /usr/local/var/data/binlog.002`

Done, works fine.

Comment: @wylkon this also happens to me and I need to touch the binlog file manually whenever it fails to restart sphinx. do you know if this should be done automatically by sphinx?